# How do I get Windows 8 RTM without a MSDN account?

Tags: windows-8

I <strike>want</strike> NEED Windows 8 RTM, but sadly don't have MSDN access.  Is there any way that I can try out the Windows 8 OS without the costly MSDN access?

Comment: You wait until Oct 25 like everyone else.  TechNet is a great deal more on the affordable side, of course, the TechNet license itself is restrictive.  Its not designed for the normal user which you most certainly are if you don't have MSDN access.

Comment: @Ramhound TechNet is still more expensive than what I as a student can afford.

Comment: It is only $90 more then what the retail price of Windows 8 Pro is likely to cost.  Even if you factor into the discounted upgrade price its very affordable.  If you are actually a STUDENT then there is DreamSpark Premium which you get through your school.

Comment: @Ramhound DreamSpark doesn't have Windows 8 RTM right now.  Also, as a user I really wouldn't want to pay $90 more for something that I'm wanting to try out.  Is it really that big of a deal to ask if there's a way to get it without MSDN/TechNet access?

Comment: Dreamspark will have it Aug 24th.  I am giving you options and pointing the options you do have are reasonable.

Comment: @Ramhound Then by all means add these as answers.  I will gladly upvote and consider accepting the best answer that is presented.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can by getting the [Enterprise Evaluation Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/jj554510.aspx)!

> This evaluation provides a 90-day trial of Windows 8 Enterprise
>   edition. Both 32-bit and 64-bit versions are available as ISO images
>   in the following languages: Chinese (Simplified), Chinese
>   (Traditional), English, English (UK), French, German, Italian,
>   Japanese, Korean, Portuguese (Brazil), and Spanish. In order to use
>   this evaluation, you must register and the product must be activated
>   online with Microsoft-hosted activation and validation services.

However it comes with a few big stipulations:

> - The evaluation edition **will expire and cannot be upgraded**.
> - To upgrade, the evaluation must be uninstalled and a non-evaluation version of Windows must be re-installed from your original installation media.
> - Consider running the evaluation edition in a virtual environment or installing on a separate hard drive or partition. The will allow you to upgrade your original Windows installation to Windows 8.
> - During registration (required) you must login with a Microsoft account and provide your name, e-mail address and country.
> - You are required to activate the product online within 10 days after installing.
> - **Once the evaluation is installed, you cannot upgrade.** To revert to a previous version of Windows, you must do a clean install from your original installation media.

Basically you can't perform the sweet upgrade deal that Windows is offering to current Win 7 users (or Win 8 RC users with valid Win 7 licenses)

Answer (score 1):

As a student, you can use [Dreamspark to access Windows 8 RTM on Aug 25, 2012](http://www.neowin.net/news/windows-8-for-dreamspark-students-coming-august-25th).