# Where to download Windows 8 trial version?

Tags: windows-8, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get Windows 8 RTM without a MSDN account?](https://superuser.com/questions/464459/how-do-i-get-windows-8-rtm-without-a-msdn-account)

Does Windows 8 has a trial version released? If so where can I download it?

Tried the [Windows 8 web site](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows-8/meet) but cant seem to find a link to download a Windows 8 Trial Version.

Comment: You wait an unknown amount of time until its offered by Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before windows was released you could download the Release candidates and use them as much as you wanted. But that does make sense now as there are allot of bugs and disabled features.

The Enterprise evaluation is a good link (you need a MSN login though) but might not be around for too long. It is to promote the development of applications and will only be available through Technet and MSDN after a period.

Windows wants you to buy this version and the prices are reasonable any way.
Upgrades starting form £75

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to windows 8 'trial' is the [enterprise evaluation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/jj554510.aspx) - it runs for 90 days, and you need to activate before August 15, 2013. As with previous trial versions/non activated versions, it will start to shutdown hourly.